# Safely casting a non-generic Collection to a homogeneous generic Collection

Tags: java, generics

I'm using a method like this to cast a non-generic Collection to a homogeneous generic Collection safely, ie throwing a ClassCastException immediately:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> safeCastCollection(final Collection collection, final Class<T> targetClass) {
    if (collection == null) {
        return null;
    }
    collection.forEach(targetClass::cast);
    return (Collection<T>) collection;
}
```

Now it would be nice to have the method not return Collection, but a collection of the same base type (Set, List, …) as the input parameter. The best I can do is this:

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>, I extends C> C safeCastCollection2(final I collection, final Class<T> targetClass) {
    if (collection == null) {
        return null;
    }
    collection.forEach(targetClass::cast);
    return (C) collection;
}
```

This works in most cases except the last:

```
List listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
Set setOfNumbers = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));

Collection<String> l0 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class);
// Collection<Integer> l1 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-)
// List<String> l2 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-(

Collection<String> l3 = safeCastCollection2(listOfStrings, String.class);
// Collection<Integer> l4 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-)
List<String> l5 = safeCastCollection2(listOfStrings, String.class); // no compiler error :-)

Set<Number> l6 = safeCastCollection2(setOfNumbers, Integer.class);
Collection<Number> l7 = safeCastCollection2(setOfNumbers, Integer.class);
// List<Number> l8 = safeCastCollection2(setOfNumbers, Integer.class); // compiler error :-)

Collection<String> l9 = safeCastCollection2(setOfNumbers, Integer.class); // no compiler error :-(
final String next = l9.iterator().next(); // runtime exception
```

Any ideas how to improve the constraint on the input parameter?

Comment: This is generally unsafe, because somebody might have a reference to the same list and add stuff to it after you did the cast. You should return a copy, or just not do this.

Comment: You probably can't do better than the first one plus overloads for the main subinterfaces.

Comment: @Radiodef I'm handling immutable (or effectively immutable) collections here, which I left out of the example to keep it simple. And even if I returned a copy, how does that change the question of constraining the input parameter?

Comment: Shouldn't that be Collection<Integer> as the return value in l9?

Comment: Shouldn't that be Collection<Integer> as the return value in l9?

Comment: @SteveB. That's the point. The compiler does not signal an error here, so the code runs into a runtime exception in the next line. That's why I'm asking if it's possible to refine the constraint on the method's input parameter.

Comment: @ujay68 As an aside: in case you don't know, allowing `Collection` references to hold `null` is considered to be a code smell ([Effective Java, Item 43](http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/43)).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be too verbose for you?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Collection<T> safeCastCollection(final Collection collection, final Class<T> targetClass) {
    return (Collection<T>) typeCheckedCollection(collection, targetClass);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> safeCastCollection(final List list, final Class<T> targetClass) {
    return (List<T>) typeCheckedCollection(list, targetClass);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Set<T> safeCastCollection(final Set set, final Class<T> targetClass) {
    return (Set<T>) typeCheckedCollection(set, targetClass);
}

// etc. for other Collection subinterfaces

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes,unchecked")
private static Collection typeCheckedCollection(final Collection collection, final Class<?> targetClass) {
    if (collection != null) {
        collection.forEach(targetClass::cast);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

This would fulfill your requirements (note that I replaced `<Number>` with `<? extends Number>`, because `Set<Integer>` cannot be assigned to `Set<Number>`):

```
    List listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
    Set setOfNumbers = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}));

    Collection<String> l0 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class);
// Collection<Integer> l1 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-)
// List<String> l2 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-(

    Collection<String> l3 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class);
// Collection<Integer> l4 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // compiler error :-)
    List<String> l5 = safeCastCollection(listOfStrings, String.class); // no compiler error :-)

    Set<? extends Number> l6 = safeCastCollection(setOfNumbers, Integer.class);
    Collection<? extends Number> l7 = safeCastCollection(setOfNumbers, Integer.class);
// List<Number> l8 = safeCastCollection(setOfNumbers, Integer.class); // compiler error :-)

// Collection<String> l9 = safeCastCollection(setOfNumbers, Integer.class); // compiler error :-)
```

Comment: Thanks. No, not too verbose, of course. I could easily do that for the couple of subinterfaces of Collection that my specific code needs, but it's not generalized, so I was wondering if there is some generics magic that would make it general for all possible subinterfaces of collection.

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd need something like `I extends Collection` as the raw `Collection` type, and then `C extends I & Collection<T>` as target `Collection` type, but compiler does not allow it ("Type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds"). So it seems it's just not possible.